# How to enable MMCSS in C# app?

Tags: c#, multithreading, multimedia

I want to try Multimedia Class Scheduler Service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684247(v=VS.85).aspx

I hope it can reduce latency by scheduling my threads better.

**How can it be done in C# ?**

*Note: my app is nothing to do with multimedia I just need features of MMCSS.*

Comment: Is it legal that another site copied this question and answer without giving credit to SO?    http://www.javacms.tech/questions/1848217/how-to-enable-mmcss-in-c-sharp-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each thread that is performing work
>   related to a particular task calls the
>   AvSetMmMaxThreadCharacteristics  or
>   AvSetMmThreadCharacteristics  function
>   to inform MMCSS that it is working on
>   that task.

It would seem all you need is to P/Invoke one or other of those API calls.

However, I suspect all that will be in vain when the garbage collector steps in and messes things up.

Have you done any profiling of the app to see what's going on under the covers? If you app is truly that latency sensitive then C# is probably the wrong choice of language to be honest.

Comment: I know this is wrong choice. But this is only choice and nothing I can do about it.. What I CAN do is to ensure the latency is minimized... and what makes you think there is GC involved anyway?

Comment: @Bobb - It's C#, you can't avoid the garbage collector!

Comment: oh really :) wonna bet money on it?

Comment: I'm intrigued as to how you think you can avoid GC in a managed language.  You can minimise it sure, but you can't avoid it altogether.

Comment: the answer is simple if you create only instances you need GC will not kick in or you can delay it for hours if you use little memory.

Comment: Obviously, don't allocate anything while running audio synthesis. ;-) I get it. A massive PITA, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the point of using the MMCSS would be in a managed application. After all, the point of the MMCSS is to adjust the scheduling priority of the process to avoid stalls during multimedia stream processing - we're talking nanosecond level scheduling. But with a managed language where a garbage collection can happen *at any time* and potentially take tens or even hundreds of *milliseconds*, then I'm not sure what benefit the MMCSS would provide that wouldn't be totally wiped out by garbage collection.

With that in mind, I wouldn't expect to see a managed interface to the MMCSS any time soon. You can certainly access it via P/Invoke, but I wouldn't expect miracles from it :)

Comment: I am just curious. every question I asked in SO, the answers start with - you cant, you dont, you shouldnt, you dont need it.... why?..anyway. could you please give me an idea what do I need to call to use MMCSS? Is it like call to "start" in the beginning and "stop" in the end? or is it more complext? what those methods could be?

Comment: Agree with BB. IF you don't see the point, don't bother answering.